# Should I quit PhD in Germany to apply for Top Universities because of Personal Reasons?

Tags: phd, united-states, academic-life, early-career

I guess similar questions have been asked but I didn't find one which is close to mine.

To my background: I have two bachelor degrees in two natural sciences from a well known university in Germany (GPA 3.3 and 3.2) in city AAA. For my master degree I moved to the small town BBB (Germany again with a well known university in my field of expertise) and finished it recently with a perfect GPA of 4.0.
Within the next 6 months I expect to publish around ~5 papers, some of them are mainly software projects. Surprisingly, quite a few people tell me that I'm somehow talented which I didn't really expect if I think back to my first years of studies.
Also I got accepted to a quite competitive PhD program with an excellent salary for my position. I started the position in December '21.

However, the main reason I stayed in BBB was because of a combination of my (6 years) relationship & the academic conditions here. Recently, it turned out that this relationship will end which puts myself in an emotional vacuum (complex story which I don't want to tell here).

Thinking of how I can change my life to give myself hope/motivation again, I thought about applying to top universities in the US. The main issue is that most deadlines are in December '22 which means that the PhD would start in fall '23. By that time, I'm going to turn 28 years old.

For me the main questions would be:

- is it worth to move to a top university to get my PhD degree? By finishing that degree I would be around 33 years old. In the meantime until fall '23 I could probably work in a startup from a popular professor in our field in the US. Potentially we could also publish papers there.
- to stay in city BBB. Most likely, I will be the *star* in our group for the next 2-3 years (our group shrinked quite a bit in the past month). My professor also agreed that I can do a few internship in top companies or different research groups (I did a 3 month stay before starting my PhD in the US). Realistically, I could finish my PhD within the next 3 years. Afterwards, the plan would be to continue as PostDoc in a top group in my field.

I guess we can boil it down to:

- PhD in a top group
  vs
- PhD in mediocre group + PostDoc in top group

which would be the steps I could achieve until I'm ~33.

Is there someone who had a similar situation in the past? How would my decision affect the possibilities to get a permanent position in academia (preferably in Germany)?
I mean, a PhD from a top university in the US basically keeps all doors open both in academia and industry.
I'm quite aware that this is only one piece in my career but this decision might have a big influence on my whole life.
Also, I'm emotionally quite damaged/sad because of the relationship in BBB. That's also the main reason why I have the urge feeling that I have to change my life drastically.

Best,

Confused Scientist

PS: I don't want to sound arrogant and that's also not my intention here. I just want to be as honest as possible.

Comment: "Here is my situation, tell me what I should do." style questions aren't really suitable here. We might be able to do "What factors should I consider?" or "I want to accomplish this, how do I get there?", but keep in mind that if the question is so specialized that only you would benefit from the answer, it's not for here.

Comment: Yeah I agree on that!

That's why I tried to boil it down whether a PhD from a top university outperforms the PhD + PostDoc path.

Comment: Outperforms regarding what metric?

Comment: that it might be easier to get an academic position in Germany.
I know for sure that even at top universities in Germany, a label such as MIT, Stanford, Berkely improves the application significantly.

Answer (score 3):

The wisest thing I've been told in this context is that in academia there are no "top universities". There are only top universities in a field. By what you are saying, you are already at one of those, so I don't think wasting almost two years to get to a slightly better one is worth the effort. From what I can gather you are also not doing anything that is reliant on better funding for experiments.

Also note that the route to a PhD in the US is much different from that of Germany. Depending on where you apply you might be required to do another master's worth of coursework.

In any case, if you decide to stay in academia, people care what your PhD was about and possibly what other work you did and much less where you did it. If you decide to leave academia, no one really cares where your PhD is from. In particular since you say you have several software-projects, you will probably end up with more job offers than resumes you sent out, if you choose to go in that direction.